# How can I determine the "name" or type of a custom object?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

Assume the custom book object described in the [developer guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/build-model#creating_pre-defined_collaborative_objects)

```
myApp.Book = function() {}
gapi.drive.realtime.custom.registerType(myApp.Book, 'Book');
myApp.Book.prototype.title = gapi.drive.realtime.custom.collaborativeField('title');
// ... other fields
var book = model.create('Book');
model.getRoot().set('book', book);
```

Is there any way for another client to know that the object at `model.getRoot().get('book')` is a `'Book'`?

The API will tell you whether or not it is a custom object (`gapi.drive.realtime.custom.isCustomObject(model.getRoot().get('book')) == true`), but not what the type of the custom object is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the client should be able to assume the type based on the data model structure.

If your data model structure is ambiguous, you could add a "name" property to each of your custom objects to distinguish.

Just set a value in the initializer.  (See https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/build-model#registering_and_creating_custom_objects)

Comment: This a good solution for an application but I am writing a library on top of the realtime api. My current workaround is to put a map from object ids to the type names in the model root. I don't love hijacking  the model, but without a way to get the name from the realtime api it seems to be the only way to get the type information to all clients